# UploadModule is not installed into web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, web-config

When i tried to upload image, getting error

```
UploadModule is not installed into web.config
```

please help to find out the solution.

Comment: Is there anything more to the error? A full stacktrace maybe?

Comment: http://amitbrothers.blogspot.com/2011/01/uploadmodule-is-not-installed-into.html

Comment: I guess you are using different file uploader than default asp file uploader..

Comment: Yes am using ajax file uploader

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Context.Items[typeof(CuteWebUI.UploadModule)] = true;
}
```